# Reference request: Transformations under which the discriminant is invariant

Tags: reference-request, quadratics

I had an occasion to think about this quadratic equation:
$$
ax^2 +bx(1-x) + c(1-x)^2 = 0.
$$
Its solution is
$$
x = \frac{2c-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac\,}}{2(a-b+c)}.
$$
The thing under the radical is the same thing we were all taught in eighth or ninth grade. The mapping $(a,b,c)\mapsto (a-b+c, b-2c, c)$ doesn't change it. Is this an instance of the conclusion of some well known result?

Comment: This is not quite true. After the transformation $(a,b,c)\to(A-B+C,B-2C,C)$ we have $\frac{4C-B\pm \sqrt{B^2-4 A C}}{2 (A-2 B+4 C)}$

Comment: @Cesareo: You're wrong. Check your algebra or post it.

Comment: @Clayton Please. Try the MATHEMATICA script 


`f = a x^2 + b x (1 - x) + c (1 - x)^2;
sols = Solve[f == 0, x];
x0 = x /. sols;
x0 /. {a -> A - B + C, b -> B - 2 C, c -> C}`

Comment: @Cesareo they meant the transfomation applied to $ax^2+bx+c$, which result is $ax^2+bx(1-x)+c(1-x)^2=(a-b+c)x^2+(b-2c)x+c$.

Comment: @scentofthetrees OK. This clarification would be interesting if it were included in the text of the question.

Comment: The discriminant of a general polynomial is invariant, up to scaling, under a projective transformation of the variable. Can you find a projective transformation of $x$ that takes $ax^2+bx+c$ to $ax^2+bx(1-x)+c(1-x)^2$?

Comment: BTW, this came about because I was looking for inflection points between $0$ and $1$ of the function $x\mapsto x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}.$ The measure $$ \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx \quad \text{for } 0\le x\le 1 $$ is a probability measure. If $X$ is a random variable with that distribution then we have $\operatorname E(X) = \alpha/(\alpha+\beta) = \mu$ (where the last equality defines $\mu$) and so of course $\operatorname E(1-X) = \beta/(\alpha+\beta) = \nu,$ and$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\, \operatorname{var}(X) = \mu\nu/\kappa$ where $\kappa = \alpha+\beta+1.$ A theorem states that $$ \frac{X - \operatorname E(X)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X)}} = \frac{X-\mu}{\sqrt{\mu\nu/\kappa}} $$ converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution $$ \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx $$ as $\kappa\to+\infty$ with $\mu,\nu$ fixed. That implies the inflection points of the probability density in my comment above this one should approach $\mu\pm\sqrt{\mu\nu/\kappa}.$ I was checking that in order to make sure I wasn't making some clumsy mistakes in a calculation. $\qquad$

Comment: (I suppose it's problematic to say something approaches something that depends on $\kappa$ as $\kappa$ approaches something. But of course what is meant is that the inflection points of the probability density of $(X-\mu)/\sqrt{\mu\nu/\kappa\,}$ approach $\pm1$ as $\kappa\to+\infty$ with $\mu,\nu$ fixed.) $\qquad$

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. Fixing $\mu$ and $\nu$ determines $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Hence, how can $\kappa =\alpha + \beta +1$ go to infinity with $\mu$ and $\nu$ fixed?

Comment: @OliverJones : Fixing $\mu$ and $\nu$ certainly does not determine $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ For example, if $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=3,$ then $\mu=2/5$ and $\nu=3/5,$ and if $\alpha=20$ and $\beta=30$ then $\mu=2/5$ and $\nu=3/5. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, you're right. I didn't look at the equations closely enough.  There is redundancy in your description though because $\mu + \nu =1$ and $\alpha +\beta =\frac{1}{\mu}\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)=ax^2+bx(1-x)+c(1-x)^2$. Then

\begin{align}
P(x)&=ax^2+bx(1-x)+c(1-x)^2\\
    &=x^2\big [a+b(\frac{1}{x}-1)+c(\frac{1}{x}-1)^2\big ]
\end{align}

Hence, $P(x)$ is obtained from $a+bx+cx^2$ by a projective transformation. Also,

\begin{align}
a+bx+cx^2 &= x^2\big [a\frac{1}{x^2}+b\frac{1}{x}+c\big ]\\
\end{align}

and so $a+bx+cx^2$ can be obtained from $Q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ by a projective transformation. It's well known that the discriminant is invariant under these projective transformations and so we have that the discriminant of $P(x)$ is equal to the discriminant of $Q(x)$.

Comment: Since I put the "reference request" tag here, can you cite some textbook that gives a precise statement of the theorem and perhaps discusses implications in algebra or geometry?

Comment: After reading this I did a dumb brute-force computation and found that the discriminant of $$ a\left( \frac{px+q}{rx+s} \right)^2 + b \left( \frac{px+q}{rx+s} \right) + c $$ is $(b^2-4ac)(ps-qr)^2,$ the second factor being $\det\begin{bmatrix} p & q \\ r & s \end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: In your original example, there is no homothety and so the scaling factor is 1. In the example you've given in the comment, there are homotheties and so there'll be scaling of the discriminant. Try to decompose the transformation into elementary projective transformations. As far as references go, you can start with the one in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything special here. Suppose that:

$$(a,b,c)\mapsto (a+x b+yc, b+zc, c)$$

Condition:

$$(b+zc)^2-4(a+xb+yc)c=b^2-4ac$$

leads to:

$$x=\frac z2,\quad y=\frac{z^2}{4}$$

You can easly construct infinitely many "nice" mappings, just pick even integer value for $z$:

$$(a,b,c)\mapsto (a+3b+9c, b+6c, c)$$

$$(a,b,c)\mapsto (a-4b+16c, b-8c, c)$$

Radical is also symmetrical with respect to $a,c$ so you can swap their roles and construct additional examples, like:

$$(a,b,c)\mapsto (a, b-8a, c-4b+16a)$$

More general linear mappings are also possible but I don't find much value in investigating it further.